# Django CSRF Protection GraphQL API

Tags: python, django, graphql, csrf

I do have a graphqlAPI which I use for CRUD Operations to my database. The authentication is tokenbased. So if an user wants to make cruds (mutations) to my database, it needs a valid token in order to do that.

What I dont know is if my graphql API is also protected against CSRF attacks as I exempt this protection with csrf_exempt
[image]

without csrf_exempt it needs a csrf token.
Is there a way to ask for a valid csrf token without sending it over the frontend ? The graphql api is only used for the backend for inserting data into the database in which I cant get the csrf token over the frontend.

Backend/Frontend: Django
Database: Mongo

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the authentication token is transported in a header field (rather than in a cookie), there is no need for CSRF protection. This is because if a user is tricked into making an unwanted request to the endpoint, the browser will *not* automatically insert the token into the request, so it will be unauthenticated. You could also say that the authentication token already serves as anti-CSRF token.

Browsers *will* automatically insert (non same-site, non third-party) cookies into requests, by contrast.